# Не могу подключиться к Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

В общем, создал базу данных через WSL(можно сказать, что это терминал линукс). Пытаюсь подключится через DBeaver, но получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, быть может, что кто-то уже сталкивался с этой проблемой или догадывается о её решении

Comment: Что нативный постгрес не ставилось?)

Comment: @eri, немного не пойму вам вопрос

Comment: Обычный, виндовый постгрес

Comment: очень интересно, но ничего не понятно... в какой момент появляется ошибка? тест подключения к серверу делали?

Comment: @SAnton, да я делал тест подключения, но следовала точно такая же ошибка

Comment: попробуй переустановить DBeaver c английским языком, и посмотреть что в этой ошибке, сейчас видимо, кодировка работает криво. + сам по себе DBeaver бывает чудит и после перезапуска работает корректно. Имей ввиду что для 32 системы используйте DBeaver не выше версии 6.0.0.

Comment: @SAnton, наверно, в это трудно будет поверить, я сменил локаль, но странные символы остались

Comment: @palpatinesheev , попробуй дополнить вопрос скинами настроек, возможно это поможет с ответом. К другим БД подключения пробовал делать? у тебя не 32 версия системы (она уже морально устарела, к сожалению, это надо признать и дать ей обрести покой)?  есть сервис https://app.supabase.com/ на нем делать что-то рабочее не  уверен, что правильно, но для всяких домашек или тестовых доступов вполне удобно? Кстати, возможно, у тебя сам "сервер" с БД чудит?